# How to use session.getLastAccessedTime()?

Tags: jsp, timeout, logout

I've to use a mechanism to track the last user logout (or when his session expired), can I do this?

I've read about this method `session.getLastAccessedTime();` but I don't understand how it works. So, there are methods to get timestamp when user was disconnected from my web page (Logout or Timeout)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to look at implementing an `HttpSessionListener`.  Using this you can fire some code each and every time a HTTP Session gets destroyed.

Here is the [API documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

Don't forget to register it in web.xml e.g.

```
<listener>
<listener-class>yourpackage.SessionDestroyedLogger</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But I've a question. I've a login.jsp page and when user open this page, tomcat notify me that a session was created. When user choose logout action, my session was invalidate (with session.invalidate() method). So, can I create a session only when user wah logged into my site?

Comment: So you're trying to create an HTTP Session only when the user does some action e.g. pressed the login button?  Sessions are a key part of server side Java - so some of your framework code (e.g. JSF, Struts, etc.) may well create it.  Or the JSP might.  Set the following directive in your JSP <%@page language="java" session="false" %>  To be honest I think you should set an attribute in the session if the user has logged in e.g. hasLoggedIn = Boolean.TRUE and just read that in the destroy method of the HttpSessionListener.